# Convert long string to data.frame

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, read.table

This is a noob question, but I am getting crazy on this. I have a character vector named bars.list which I download from a FTP Sever. The vector looks like this:

```
"\"\",\"times\",\"open\",\"high\",\"low\",\"close\",\"numEvents\",\"volume\"\r\n\"1\",2015-05-18 06:50:00,23.98,23.98,23.5,23.77,421,0\r\n\"2\",2015-05-18 07:50:00,23.77,23.9,23.34,23.6,720,0\r\n\"3\",2015-05-18 08:50:00,23.6,23.6,23.32,23.42,720,0\r\n\"4\",2015-05-18 09:50:00,23.44,23.91,23.43,23.66,720,0\r\n\"5\",2015-05-18 10:50:00,23.67,24.06,23.59,24.02,720,0\r\n\"6\",2015-05-18 11:50:00,24.02,24.04,23.32,23.33,720,0\r\n\"7\",2015-05-18 12:50:00,23.33,23.42,22.74,22.81,720,0\r\n\"8\",2015-05-18 13:50:00,22.79,22.92,22.49,22.69,720,0\r\n\"9\",2015-05-18 14:50:00,22.69,22.7,22.14,22.14,481,0\r\n\"10\",2015-05-19 06:50:00,21.09,21.49,20.82,21.47,421,0\r\n\"11\",2015-05-19 07:50:00,21.48,21.68,21.46,21.51,720,0\r\n\"12\",2015-05-19 08:50:00,21.51,21.93,21.45,21.92,720,0\r\n\"13\",2015-05-19 09:50:00,21.92,21.92,21.55,21.55,720,0\r\n\"
```

I need to have this vector converted into usable format but

```
> read.table(bars.list, header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote = "", dec = ".")
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file '"","times","open","high","low","close","numEvents","volume"
"1",2015-05-18 06:50:00,23.98,23.98,23.5,23.77,421,0
"2",2015-05-18 07:50:00,23.77,23.9,23.34,23.6,720,0
"3",2015-05-18 08:50:00,23.6,23.6,23.32,23.42,720,0
"4",2015-05-18 09:50:00,23.44,23.91,23.43,23.66,720,0
```

It is not clear to me why R tells me that some Connection cannot be opened as the object is already pasted as an argument to the function. The output R Shows me with a warning sign is already pretty close to what I need...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are two options.  The first one offers a fix to your current code, and the second looks at a simpler more efficient alternative.

**Option 1:** The first argument in `read.table()` is `file`. You are reading from a vector not from a file, so you need to use the `text` argument, with `text = bars.list`.

Also, we can get rid of all the quotes with `gsub()` first and then use 
`read.csv()` instead of `read.table()` since `header = TRUE` and `sep = ","` are the defaults there.

```
read.csv(text = gsub("\"", "", bars.list), row.names = 1)
#                  times  open  high   low close numEvents volume
# 1  2015-05-18 06:50:00 23.98 23.98 23.50 23.77       421      0
# 2  2015-05-18 07:50:00 23.77 23.90 23.34 23.60       720      0
# 3  2015-05-18 08:50:00 23.60 23.60 23.32 23.42       720      0
# 4  2015-05-18 09:50:00 23.44 23.91 23.43 23.66       720      0
# 5  2015-05-18 10:50:00 23.67 24.06 23.59 24.02       720      0
# 6  2015-05-18 11:50:00 24.02 24.04 23.32 23.33       720      0
# 7  2015-05-18 12:50:00 23.33 23.42 22.74 22.81       720      0
# 8  2015-05-18 13:50:00 22.79 22.92 22.49 22.69       720      0
# 9  2015-05-18 14:50:00 22.69 22.70 22.14 22.14       481      0
# 10 2015-05-19 06:50:00 21.09 21.49 20.82 21.47       421      0
# 11 2015-05-19 07:50:00 21.48 21.68 21.46 21.51       720      0
# 12 2015-05-19 08:50:00 21.51 21.93 21.45 21.92       720      0
# 13 2015-05-19 09:50:00 21.92 21.92 21.55 21.55       720      0
```

For me this worked better than using the `quote` argument in `read.csv()`.

**Option 2:** `fread()` from the *data.table* package works nicely too.  It is faster and the code is cleaner.  No need to use `gsub()` with it. We can put `bars.list` in directly and drop the first column.

```
data.table::fread(bars.list, drop = 1)
```

Now, you will get a warning with this method due to the final `\"` quote.  You can either live with it or get a warning-less result by removing that last quote mark.

```
data.table::fread(sub("\"$", "", bars.list), drop = 1)
```

**Data:**

```
bars.list <- "\"\",\"times\",\"open\",\"high\",\"low\",\"close\",\"numEvents\",\"volume\"\r\n\"1\",2015-05-18 06:50:00,23.98,23.98,23.5,23.77,421,0\r\n\"2\",2015-05-18 07:50:00,23.77,23.9,23.34,23.6,720,0\r\n\"3\",2015-05-18 08:50:00,23.6,23.6,23.32,23.42,720,0\r\n\"4\",2015-05-18 09:50:00,23.44,23.91,23.43,23.66,720,0\r\n\"5\",2015-05-18 10:50:00,23.67,24.06,23.59,24.02,720,0\r\n\"6\",2015-05-18 11:50:00,24.02,24.04,23.32,23.33,720,0\r\n\"7\",2015-05-18 12:50:00,23.33,23.42,22.74,22.81,720,0\r\n\"8\",2015-05-18 13:50:00,22.79,22.92,22.49,22.69,720,0\r\n\"9\",2015-05-18 14:50:00,22.69,22.7,22.14,22.14,481,0\r\n\"10\",2015-05-19 06:50:00,21.09,21.49,20.82,21.47,421,0\r\n\"11\",2015-05-19 07:50:00,21.48,21.68,21.46,21.51,720,0\r\n\"12\",2015-05-19 08:50:00,21.51,21.93,21.45,21.92,720,0\r\n\"13\",2015-05-19 09:50:00,21.92,21.92,21.55,21.55,720,0\r\n\""
```